# How toggle multiple element with one .toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question is kind of weird but i am not able to find out this

**For Example :** there is some div with ids

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1">test 1</div>
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
<div id="test3">test 3</div>
<div id="test4">test 4</div>
<div id="test5">test 5</div>
<div id="test6">test 6</div>
```

and i want to toggle some specific div 
like

```
test1, test4 and test6
```

so i have to do like this

```
$('#test1').toggle();
$('#test4').toggle();
$('#test6').toggle();
```

but i want to know is there any way to do that like

```
$('#test1', '#test4', '#test6').toggle();
```

I know it can be done if i just give same class on the div which i want to toggle.

but i want to know this for that reason i asked

Comment: `$('#test1, #test4, #test6').toggle();` - you only use two `'`'s

Comment: @Turnip your solved it a big thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can, simply comma separate your ID selector:

```
$('#test1, #test4, #test6').toggle();
```

```js
$("#toggle").on("click", function(){
  $('#test1, #test4, #test6').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE 1, 4, 6</button>

<div id="test1">test 1</div>
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
<div id="test3">test 3</div>
<div id="test4">test 4</div>
<div id="test5">test 5</div>
<div id="test6">test 6</div>
```

A much **reusable code** would allow you to toggle any desired elements without copy/pasting your JavaScript functions.
**Here's an example** where the desired selector to toggle is stored within the `data-toggle` attribute of the action element:

```js
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function(){
    $(this.dataset.toggle).toggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-toggle="#test1,#test6">Toggle 1, 6</button>
<button data-toggle="#test3,#test4">Toggle 3, 4</button>

<div id="test1">test 1</div>
<div id="test2">test 2</div>
<div id="test3">test 3</div>
<div id="test4">test 4</div>
<div id="test5">test 5</div>
<div id="test6">test 6</div>

<button data-toggle=".info">Toggle .info</button>

This is some
<span class="info">OLD</span>
<span class="info hidden">NEW!!!</span>
info
```